# Shrink UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I found this: http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.it/2011/06/how-does-uitableviewcell-reorder.html on the web and I think it's very useful, indeed I implemented it into my app. Now I will ask you if anyone knows how to hide the UITableCell when the view is loaded.
If you use this code it works but when the table view is loaded it shows all the expanded. How I can see the cell shrink when it load the view?

Comment: THis is the best site https://www.cocoacontrols.com/ search on it "UITableView".. lots of application you find out from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean collapse the sections, so that only the section header shows up until a used taps it?

Implement [tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3anumberOfRowsInSection%3a) to return 0 if the section is not open and the actual number of rows if open.

**Update**: I had to run before I could take a good look at the source and flesh out my answer:

`MainController.m` of the sample code is where that method is implemented (the .xib sets MainController as the delegate of the table view).

If you want one section open at a time, have one variable in MainCotroller that stores the open section. In tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: do something like this:

```
if (section == [self openSection])
{
    return [[cellCount objectAtIndex:section] intValue];
}

return 0;
```

Obviously you haveto set `openSection` when a user taps it. If you want multiple open sections, instead of storing one `NSInteger` for the currently open section, just keep a bool array.

**Update 2**

That example actually uses an array, `cellCount`, to hold the number of cells for each section. When the button is tapped, `cellCount` switches between 0 and the actual number of cells.

The end effect is the same (`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns 0 for collapsed sections) but there's no reason to change the method in the example to what I posted above, all you have to do is initialize the `cellCount` array to hold all 0's, and then everything else will work as intended.

So, all you have to do is look at `viewDidLoad` in `MainController.m` and change the line

`[cellCount addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[_cellArray count]]];`

to

`[cellCount addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];`

Comment: I will try your solution, but I'm sure that will works. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @user2478615 I've updated my answer since your comment, take a look if you're having trouble

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution. In your method openSection I've to detect a touch event on the display of the device right?

Comment: `openSection` is an `NSInteger` property that stores the number of the open section. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` takes an `NSInteger` for the requested section, so that is being compared to the currently open section. If section 1 is open and it asks for the number of rows in section 1, it returns the number of rows, otherwise it returns 0. The touch event detection is a separate thing, i.e. if you detect a touch on section 3, set openSection = 3

Comment: I'm trying it, but it's not working. I stored the number of section in a property. I inserted your solution in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:. So it has this flow:
1. The main view is loaded, I swipe right to see the table view
2. Before it draws the table view, it parse an XML file and it runs all the table view method
3. So when I tap on the button that's inside the section header, I store the index in the property openSection
4. When the program calls again the method tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:, the variable section has value 14 and the property openSection has another value.

Comment: @user2478615 Sounds correct up to step 4. `section` is the passed in variable, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` will be called for *each* section that you have. If `openSection` is set, then one of those methods will return non-0, and the rest will return 0. Also, make sure to call `[tableView reloadData]` after a touch to update the table.

Comment: It does, indeed the last instruction of the method that handle the tap over the button is [self.tableShow reloadData];. I made so: at the start I assigned to openSection value -1, then in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: I check if openSection is equal to -1 and i return 0 (this is working). Next step: I tap on the first button, I change the value of openSection to 0, so in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:, the program will not enter to the check i made before. I put return [[cellCount objectAtIndex:section]intValue]; and it will show the content of all cell but not the first one

Comment: I wanted to see only the first cells when I tap on the first section button, but for now it shows the cell from the second to the 14...

Comment: @user2478615 I missed the part in the sample code where they actually do exactly what's supposed to be done, so my original answer was doing the same thing in a different way, which conflicts with theirs. See Update 2 in my answer - This time I actually loaded up the Mac and tried it to make sure it works, as opposed to just scanning the code on my Windows machine :) Sorry about the confusion.